# Spring Webflux Webclient: Issue with wiretap logging

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Quick question regarding Java Spring Webflux WebClient and the wiretap logging please.

I am currently using Java with SpringBoot Webflux WebClient 2.5.0 to make outbound http requests (where I am the source), I need to make a http request (to a target).

I make the outbound http client like this:

```
webClientUtil.getWebClient().mutate().baseUrl(someUrl).build().post().body(BodyInserters.fromValue(someRequest)).exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(SomeResponse.class));
```

I would like to log the request and the response, hence, I am coding the following:

```
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.HEX_DUMP)
```

inside a Util class:

```
public WebClient getWebClient() {
        final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.HEX_DUMP).metrics(true, Function.identity()).proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host(proxyUrl));
        return WebClient.create().mutate().defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
    }
```

(The WebClient implantation has been tested and working)

And I have my logging level set to INFO with `logging.level.root=INFO`

Please note the log level is info, the wiretap is also info.

Unfortunately, I am not seeing any extra logs.

What am I doing wrong please?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you subscribing to the request or passing the the response back to something that subscribes? Here's a working example that is effectively the same as your config, https://github.com/DarrenForsythe/so67670516 if you run the app it'll dump the request as expected. 

I'm wondering if the requests are happening/being subscribed to or another configuration/logging confg is affecting it

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes, I am subscribing to it, doing computations fine on the response etc. The only issue is that I am not seeing any of the wiretap logs

Comment: logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient = INFO

Have you tried setting the logging level specifically for the package?

Comment: Yes, both will not yield any extra logs

Answer (score 0):

any logback.xml file somewhere that would override the config ?

I had similar problem in some tests, and solved it by having this in my `logback-test.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

  <logger name="reactor.netty" level="debug"/>

</configuration>
```

Comment: logback-test.xml and not logback-text.xml